# ToString for list og longs

Tags: c#, list, tostring

I have a list of longs.For example:

```
List<long> myData = new List<long>{ 2 , 10, 12, 13}
```

I want to invoke ToString for this List and get a string with all list`s elements :

```
myData.ToString()
```

as a result `"2,10,12,13"` 
How can I do it? (Now when I run `ToString()` I got `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int64]`)

Comment: If a class does not implement `ToString`, you get just that. Also, how is a `List` supposed to guess how you want that string (i.e. how to combine items)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string.Join and LINQ select to achieve this, like so:

```
var dataAsString = string.Join(", ", myData.Select(s => s.ToString()));
```